# windows not booting after installing docker desktop

Tags: windows, docker, desktop

I installed docker 4.9.0, after the installation I restarted the system as suggested.

I got error "your device run into a problem and needs restart"

My system is windows 10 pro 12gb of Ram 500gb of SSD

Virtualization is enabled

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You should verify your system has hardware virtualization enabled (VT-X and/or AMD-V).  You should also make sure your BCD is correct.  You will have to [edit] your question to provide more information in order to get an answer to your question.

Comment: My virtualization is enabled. How do I check my BCD

Comment: Before I go research what the command is, since I don't know it off hand, are you able to boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: yes. I can boot into safe mode

Comment: `Bcdedit /enum /v` should provide the required information to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem is the same as
[Windows 10 v20H2 won't boot after installing docker #9477](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9477),
where one poster solved that problem by:

> In my case, I enter Safe-mode (without network adapter), then remove all network adapter except wifi & ethernet.
> Now my machine is back.

Answer (score -2):

The way I managed to solve this was to:

- enter [Safe Mode](https://support.hp.com/bg-en/document/ish_5000477-5000532-16).
- restart the computer.
- manually delete everything related to docker.

Last suggestion, don’t use docker on Windows, or at least try it out in a virtual machine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).